# How to make new column with 'duplicate and unique'

Tags: python, pandas

My `.csv` file

```
IP
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.1
192.168.1.2
192.168.1.3
```

If duplicate found in make a new column with mentioned.

Expected output:

```
IP             un_dup
-------------------------
192.168.1.1    duplicate
192.168.1.1    duplicate
192.168.1.2    unique
192.168.1.3    unique
```

My code to find the duplicate

```
IP = [('192.168.1.1'),
      ('192.168.1.1'),
      ('192.168.1.2'),
      ('192.168.1.3')]
dfIP = pd.DataFrame(IP, columns=['IP'])
dfIPdup = dfIP[dfIP.duplicated()]

#logic is we got the duplicate and now add a column and mention 'duplicate' or unique
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('input.csv')
df['un_dup'] = np.where(df['IP'].duplicated(keep=False),'duplicate', 'unique')

print(df)
```